# program for show the detail of the student as like name fathername roll no cgpa on output

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
 struct student
 {
 string::name(20) 
 string::fathername(20)
   int rollno;
   float cgpa;
  {
    student s1,s2;
     s1.name ='ali';
       s1.fathername='akram';
    s1.rollno=1;
     s1.cgpa=2.2;
     cout<<s1.name<<endl;
        cout<<s1.fathername<<endl;
       cout<<s1.rollno<<endl;
        cout<<s1.cgpa<<endl;
        getch();
     }
```

this program give me error when i use parameter in program this program give me thre error when use parameter why?

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing the issue?

Comment: You have several simple syntax errors and the compiler should have told you what's wrong in the error messages, fix these first please: `string name;` `s1.name ="ali";`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        struct student
        {
            string name;
            string fathername;
                int rollno;
                double cgpa;
        };
                student s1, s2;
                s1.name = "ali";
                s1.fathername = "akram";
                s1.rollno = 1;
                s1.cgpa = 2.2;
                cout << s1.name << endl;
                cout << s1.fathername << endl;
                cout << s1.rollno << endl;
                cout << s1.cgpa << endl;
                getchar();



        return 0;
    }
```

Your code has got a several errors. First of all I do not see a reason why you added , second important thing is that you should format your code, instead of using `string::name(20);` simply use `string name;`,third is that you have to put `;` when you are ending a struct.